# How to configure gitlab-ci.yml to generate xml report and artifact for both .NET services?

Tags: .net, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, cicd

I have to configure pipeline test results for 2 .NET services in gitlab and it works fine just for one of them, in my case my-service-2-tests. For the my-service-1-tests it doesn't generate the xml report file and neither the artifact.

This is how I configured the gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
my-service-1-tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - dotnet test $SRC_DIRECTORY/$TESTS_DIRECTORY/$MY_SERVICE_1_TESTS --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=..\artifacts\{assembly}-test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
  allow_failure: true 
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./**/*test-result.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - ./**/*test-result.xml
        
my-service-2-tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - dotnet test $SRC_DIRECTORY/$TESTS_DIRECTORY/$MY_SERVICE_2_TESTS --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=..\artifacts\{assembly}-test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
  allow_failure: true 
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./**/*test-result.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - ./**/*test-result.xml
```

First job, my-service-1-tests, throws the following error, but the test results are visible in the console when the job is runnning:

```
Failed!  - Failed:     2, Passed:    13, Skipped:     0, Total:    15, Duration: 3 s - /builds/my-app/backend/my-service-1/src/tests/MyService1.Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/MyService1.Tests.dll (net6.0)
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: src/tests/artifacts/*-test-result.xml: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/my-app/backend/my-service-1) 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

No xml report is generated for this service, but for my-service-2-tests job it works just fine, the xml report being generated in the specified path and test results are visibile in the pipeline even if the job has failed.

So far I've tried to give the absolute path to the artifact but the same error persists. I've also tried to create the artifact folder using the mkdir command.

Is there a way to fix the gitlab-ci.yml file configuration in order to have the artifact files generated accordingly for both services?

**EDIT**

Also I've noticed when executing my-service-1-tests job, git repo is reinitialized:

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/app/backend/my-service/.git/
Checking out 11csasad75 as detached HEAD (ref is branch/test-results)...
Removing "..\\..\\..\\..\\cache\\app\\backend\\my-service\\branch-test-results-4-non_protected\\cache.zip"
Removing src/.nuget/
Removing src/my-service-1/bin/
Removing src/my-service-1/obj/
Removing src/my-service-2/bin/
Removing src/my-service-2/obj/
Removing src/other-service/bin/
Removing src/other-service/obj/
Removing src/tests/my-service-1-tests/bin/
Removing src/tests/my-service-1-tests/obj/
Removing src/tests/my-service-2-tests/bin/
Removing src/tests/my-service-2-tests/obj/
Skipping Git submodules setup
```

But when my-service-2-tests is executing, an empty git repo is created:

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/app/backend/my-service/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 11csasad75 as detached HEAD (ref is branch/test-results)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
```

Could this be the issue? if yes, how can I fix it? they run in parallel

Comment: can you confirm that the test file is actually created for your first job. after running the test just give a cat path_to_test_report

Comment: The test file is not created, or at least it doesn't find it. But the test output is visible in the runner console

Comment: would suggesting change the path to a simple one say test_report.xml
then just try `ls` and check if the file is there.

Comment: I applied your suggestion and the test-report.xml is not created at all for my-service-1-tests, only for my-service-2-tests.